# Excel: Preparing Histogram Data

Tags: excel, histogram, frequency

I'd like to prepare data for a Histogram in Excel, and I dont know how.

I have a time series of measurements over a year. I know how to make a histogram on the number of measurements, but not how to make one on the measurement quantity, showing the measured quantity per time bin. So far I used the Frequency funtion

can you help me?

minimal example
[image]

Comment: Is your question not "I would like to figure out the  "Hist Measurement?" instead? if yes, `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` may do what you want

Comment: You need to choose a suitable aggregate - probably average or sum - for the measurements and group them per month perhaps using a pivot table/chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem when i discovered the syntax

```
"<"&F4   //dynamic inequality
```

for the criteria in SUMIFS(). Hence an easy solution: (and adding one more upper bin boundary)
[image]

thanks to cybernetic.nomad for making me re-consider SUMIFS(). i tried before but didnt succeed.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to create histograms automatically using Pivot tables.

1. create a pivot table of your data
2. add the variable (in your case measurement) to the rows section
3. add the variable (in your case measurement) to the values section and set it to "count". This will count the number of measurements within a bin.
4. add the individuals (in your case dates) to the columns section.
5. Select the header of the first column of your pivot table (in your case measurement) and go to "group selection" in the "pivot table analysis" tab. Here you can define the groups (bins) you want.

The result is a beautiful histogram and you can even compare differnt samples.

[image: Example automatic Histogram Excel]